# How to use urllib2 to open an 'infinite' jpg?

Tags: python, sockets, download, urllib2

I'm using urllib2 open to download some web pages.  Unfortunately one page is an infinite stream (a set of live video frames) and urllib2 will not timeout because the open call succeeds, while the 'read' call hangs forever.  Example code:

```
res = opener.open(encoded, timeout=timeout)
log('opened', url)
contents = res.read()
log('never get here')
```

Any tips on avoiding/killing these connections?

Comment: When you find the answer you like, please accept it ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the generator approach mentioned by Jacob I integrated a "kill switch".

```
startime = datetime.now()
res = opener.open(url, timeout=timeout)
contents = ''
for item in res:
  contents += item
  if (datetime.now() - starttime).seconds > timeout:
    raise IOError('timeout')
```

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a job for generators!

Imagine you have an infinate text file... lets call it test.txt now `open('test.txt').read()` will hang the machine and eventually crash, so why not yield line for line in this infinate stream in a generator e.g.

```
def yield_line(file):
    with open(file) as inp:
        for line in inp:
            yield line
```

now when initialised yield_line becomes an iterable object so this becomes legal

```
out = open('out.txt')
for line in yield_line('test.txt'):
    out.write(line.replace('1','2'))
```

Now consider that a url can operate in the same way as a file, you can just yield line for line in the url

```
def yield_url(url):
    with urllib.urlopen(url) as inp:
        for line in inp:
            yield line
```

Edit:
Timeout example

```
out = open('out.txt')
for count, line in enumerate(yield_line('test.txt')):
    if count == 444: #timeout value :D
        break
    out.write(line.replace('1','2'))
```

Comment: That is helpful, but my point was that I don't want to download an infinite file, I want to kill such downloads.  However, I used your generator strategy to solve the problem.

Comment: Generators are actually amazing, personally I believe that everything in python could be re-written with generators...

Answer (score 2):

You should examine the header to detect if it is multipart, and then drop or read the content.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a timeout on the operation as a whole i.e. the function where those lines you mentioned are defined.